# fortran find series of integers in array

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

Is there a function or method in Fortran to find as series of integers in an array and return a location in the array or count if matches?

(1, 5, 8, 56, 33, 56, 78, 123, 78, 8, 34, 33, 19, 25, 36)

find (8,56,33)

either return 3 as location or 1 as a match

If multiple:

(1, 5, 8, 56, 33, 56, 78, 123, 78, 8, 56, 33, 19, 25, 36)

find (8,56,33)

Return 3 and 10 or 2

Are there functions in fortran to handle this kind of array searching?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but give a look at [findloc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FINDLOC.html#FINDLOC)

Comment: To complete my previous comment, findloc has been added to [gfortran 9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status#line-90) and [ifort 19](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-findloc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "No", there is no such [intrinsic](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Intrinsic+procedures) function in Fortran.

You are typically be expected to write something like this yourself. For example:

- begin with an array of all possible starting indices
- determine a condition for keeping indices
- sequentially keep only those indices that satisfy your condition

The intrinsic procedure [`pack`](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/pack) is quite useful here, it can be used to only retain values from an array (your starting locations) that match a certain condition (your condition for keeping starting locations).

The (not extensively tested!) program "test.f90" below illustrates the use:

```
module mod_finder
    implicit none

    contains
        subroutine find_start_locs(array, sub_array, start_locs)
            integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
            integer, intent(in) :: sub_array(:)
            integer, allocatable, intent(out) :: start_locs(:)
            integer :: i

            ! initialize result with all possible starting indices
            start_locs = [(i, i = 1, size(array)-size(sub_array)+1)]

            ! sequentially keep only those indices that satisfy a condition
            do i = 1, size(sub_array)
                ! condition for keeping: the value of array(start_locs + i - 1) must be equal to the value of sub_array(i)
                ! use PACK to only keep start_locs that satisfy this condition
                start_locs = PACK(start_locs, array(start_locs + i - 1) == sub_array(i))
                if (size(start_locs) == 0) then
                    exit
                end if
            end do
        end subroutine find_start_locs

end module mod_finder

program test
    use mod_finder
    implicit none

    integer, allocatable :: arr(:)
    integer, allocatable :: seq(:)
    integer, allocatable :: res(:)

    ! arr = [1, 5, 8, 56, 33, 56, 78, 123, 78, 8, 34, 33, 19, 25, 36]
    arr = [1, 5, 8, 56, 33, 56, 78, 123, 78, 8, 56, 33, 19, 25, 36]
    seq = [8, 56, 33]

    call find_start_locs(arr, seq, res)

    print *, "array:     ", arr
    print *, "sequence:  ", seq
    print *, "locations: ", res
    print *, "# matches: ", size(res)

end program test
```

For the two test cases in your question, compiling and running gives the following output:

```
$ gfortran -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all test.f90
$ ./a.out

 array:                1           5           8          56          33          56          78         123          78           8          34          33          19          25          36
 sequence:             8          56          33
 locations:            3
 # matches:            1
```

and

```
 array:                1           5           8          56          33          56          78         123          78           8          56          33          19          25          36
 sequence:             8          56          33
 locations:            3          10
 # matches:            2
```

Comment: If you're working with large arrays, you may want modify the `find_start_locs` subroutine to use the method outlined in [@kvantour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57993785/3967096) to _build up_ `start_locs` instead of _stripping away_ as I do. In addition to the initial overhead, my conditional mask in `pack` needs to access non-contiguous elements of `array`, while the sliding window accesses the elements more contiguously

Answer (score 3):

What you are after is something called a sliding-window searching algorithm. A simple implementation would be the following:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: arr 
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: seq
  integer                            :: i

  arr = [1, 5, 8, 56, 33, 56, 78, 123, 78, 8, 56, 33, 19, 25, 36]
  seq = [8, 56, 33]

  do i=1,size(arr)-size(seq)+1
     if (all(arr(i:i+size(seq)-1) == seq)) print *, i
  end do
end program
```

This is not the most optimized version, but it will do the job in most cases.